Children's book series. Two sisters go through a portal to a magical school. They have a classmate who uses a wheelchair. There is a unicorn
I was read parts of several books in this series about 2020. The books seemed to have been written recently. It was set in the UK. A girl who was six or seven at the time was a huge fan. There was humour in the books. There is more than one unicorn. One of the unicorns is always making the kids laugh.The funny unicorn loves to eats donuts. Sometimes the kids bribe him with donuts to do as they ask. They are very fond of the unicorn.
The portal they travel through is in a supermarket car park.
They have a friend, who is a really kind boy. The boy is black. In the illustration he has an afro. His name might be Raheem. He is very nervous about using the magic portal. He and his dad perform some sort of ritual (not a magical ritual), to help the boy feel calm and safe. They call it something like the safety song or the safety dance.
The classes at their magical school are named after the colours of the spectrum ROYGBIV. The first years are in Red class and so on.
At the beginning of one book, the sisters are excited to soon be returning to their magical school and one of them dances around the kitchen while doing the washing up.

You tagged this as 'unicorns' - do you recall their role in the story?

@Michael. There was more than one unicorn in the books. One was always doing things that made the kids laugh.

I added the points I remembered about unicorns to my question. Thanks @Michael

This must surely be The Naughtiest Unicorn series by Pip Bird. The first book in the series is Welcome to Unicorn School, and it hits all the points mentioned in the question. The central character, Mira, has finally been selected to go to Unicorn School. Her older sister, Rani, had started attendibg the school two years previously. The portal to get there is indeed in a car park, "the car park by the leisure centre". Mira has a friend called Raheem who was very nervous about going through the portal. He and his dad had rehearsed the procedure twelve times, and finally he had to sing a song about "The Ten Rules of Keeping Safe" to calm himself down.
The classes at the school are named after colours, Mira being placed in Class Red. She does indeed have a friend, a little girl, who is in a wheelchair. Mira's unicorn is called "Dave" (a very un-unicornly name), who has an addiction to doughnuts and is something of a comedian.
